# How to prevent direct URL access to action classes

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm developing a shopping web site application. In my application, I need to prevent direct URL access to my action classes. As an example, I have an action named, OrderAdd. In this action class I'm getting some data from request scope. If someone access to this action class directly, it shows Nullpointer exceptions. How do I prevent this in my application. Has it any possible ways to this. I'm using jsp for my views. My framework is struts2. Actions are java.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you can't prevent yourself from handling NPE, the exception interceptor can do it for you.

Comment: This is an example of [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you _actually_ need to do is to prevent the showing or even the throwing of the exceptions (or perhaps just the showing of their stack traces). You don't need to "prevent direct URL access to action classes", which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are security constraints built into j2ee. You can configure URL patterns inside web.xml for which you dont want to allow direct access to..

Read here
http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security

[Source :](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security)

Use Case: We would like to exclude a set of web resources from any access. This can arise when a certain portion of the web application needs to undergo some form of maintenance or is not applicable for a particular physical deployment of a generic web application. We will achieve this with authorization constraints that specify no roles.

```
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>excluded</display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>No Access</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/excluded/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/restricted/employee/excluded/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/restricted/partners/excluded/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>No Access</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint />
   <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: @user3081492 i have updated the link and answer..this might be more useful. Good luck

Comment: Another way would be to add a Filter and block (send a 500 or blank page) for some requests) but Filter should be fast and have a cached list of deny URL patterns

Comment: @tgkprog yes.. we can write filters. but I personally find it a more neat method. I am not sure about time complexity of both the approaches though.

Comment: did not see that this can accept wild card too. As for classes will have to deny all starting with com/* ... web.xml would be better with wild cards.

Comment: @tgkprog but in filter we can use regexp to include wildcards as well.. what do you say?

Comment: As well as Filters, Struts2 provides interceptors which act in a similar way to filters, but are integrated with the rest of the Struts config. They allow you to handle any redirection etc within Struts, rather than outside of it like you'd have to do with Filters.

Comment: @begginerAll Why did you accept this answer? It's not actually useful at all for your particular case. You should only accept answers when you are sure that they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is based on a misunderstanding. The nature of a web application is that users can access any URL with any request method. You need to allow users to make valid requests to valid URLs because that is needed in the normal, correct workflows of the application. If you don't want users to see your `NullPointerException`s when they try to visit an URL without providing the required parameters, you should either use `try..catch` to catch them - or better still, avoid *causing* the `NullPointerException`s in the first place by testing for missing parameters using `if` or something.